# MVC 4: Create controller for Shared view _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do you achieve this?
This View is automatically generated.
When I manual add a View for example: Contact view with Index.cshtml file in it.

I can modify this view by writing a controller Contact.

```
    public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        @ViewBag.Test = "this text will be used in my Contact View";

        return View();
    }
}
```

So in my contact view i can do like this

```
<p> @Viewbag.Test </p>
```

And the text will be displayed.
But how do you achieve this for my _Layout.cshtml file in my Shared View?
I tried the same by adding a SharedController but not working this way

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a controller for _Layout.cshtml. This file is used for any view's layout. For example, look at the _ViewStart.cshtml file in your Views folder:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This tells basically all controllers to use that layout as a wrapper around the view returned by your controller actions.

Your _Layout.cshtml file already has a hint about one way to populate it with values:

```
<head>
    ...
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    ...
</head>
```

If you do the following in a view, it will be rendered in the head/title section of the _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@{
    @ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
```

Comment: I think you have not read the question. The OP wants to know how to access the `ViewBag` from the `_Layout.cshtml` file

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a controller for _Layout. Your contact view is added to _Layout to create one complete view. So you can use any of your ViewBag properties from your contact controller inside of _Layout also. _Layout has access to the same variables as your contact view.

Specifically, in your example:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        @ViewBag.Test = "this text will be used in my Contact View";

        return View();
    }
}
```

ViewBag.Test will also be accessible in _Layout the same way it is in your contact view.